PowerShell script refuses to exclude "symbolic link" folders
I am currently working on a script that needs to do the following :

Find all duplicate files on a specific folder based on their hash
Display their path and size
Export the results into a csv

But I don't want the script to go into subfolders that are symbolic links
And that's my issue. No matter what I do, the script refuses to ignore those "symbolic link" type subfolders
Here's what the script looks like right now, which is working aside from the "symbolic link" exclusion issue :
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse |
    Group-Object -Property Length |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    ForEach-Object Group |
    Get-FileHash |
    Group-Object Hash |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    ForEach-Object Group |
    Select-Object Path, Hash, @{ N = 'Length'; E = { [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($_.Path).Length}} |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation

The folder "C:\Users\test\Documents\folder", contains 2 sub-folders (named "Subfolder_A" and "Subfolder_B") that are symbolic links
And the script always icludes them into the search despite me not wanting to
Here's what I tried so far
I changed the Get-ChildItem line by this :
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse | Where-Object -property Attributes -NotLike -value "*ReparsePoint*" |

This :
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse | Where-Object Attributes -NotLike "*ReparsePoint*" |

And this :
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Name -notmatch ("Subfolder_A" -join "|")} |

But it stills goes into "Subfolder_A" and "Subfolder_B"
I don't know why the script refuses to bypass symbolic links.
Thanks in advance for your help

Note: Since you're using -File, the implication is that you're using at least v3 of PowerShell, so I've removed the "powershell-2.0" tag. If you do need to support an earlier version that v5.1, please use the actual minimum version.

The recurse parameter does some surprising things.  You can pipe get-childitem to itself:
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !reparsepoint | get-childitem -recurse #... 


Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It still goes into those "symbolic link" folders

It only filters the top level.


Use a three-pass approach:

First, enumerate only the files (-File) located directly in the destination dir., $srcDir.

Then recursively (-Recurse) enumerate only directories (-Directory) while excluding symlinks to directories (-Attributes !ReparsePoint)

Non-recursively enumerate each non-symlink directory's files, with Get-ChildItem -File.


& {
  Get-ChildItem -File $srcDir
  Get-ChildItem -Attributes !ReparsePoint -Directory -Recurse $srcDir |
    Get-ChildItem -File
} 

Note:

!ReparsePoint technically excludes other NTFS reparse points as well, such as directory junctions, but I presume that's desired.

While I do remember at least past Windows PowerShell versions invariably following symlinks, as of v5.1.22621.2506 I seem to now see the opposite: symlinks to directories are seemingly never followed.

PowerShell (Core) 7 by explicit design now does not follow symlinks by default, but offers an opt-in via the -FollowSymlink switch.


